# Updating the database after parsing CSV document

Tags: php, database, forms, csv

Im trying to update the database based in a CSV document, if the first value in the CVS row is equal or greater than 300, it should update the database, and so on....but I cant get it to work, the parsing of the document works. but the update doesnt.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File"/>
</form>

<?php
global $wpdb; 

if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
{
$path = get_temp_dir();
$path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
  " is uploaded<br>";
  $csvFile = $path;
  $csv = readCSV($csvFile);
}
}

/* parse CSV*/
function readCSV($csvFile){
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024); 
}
fclose($file_handle); 
return $line_of_text;
} 
/*update the DB*/
foreach($csv as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[0] >= 300){

        $email = $value[1];
        $nobility = "nobilityFive";
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->users SET mg_nobility='$nobility' WHERE user_email='$email'"));
    }
    elseif ($value[0] >= 200 && $value[0] < 300) {

        $email = $value[1];
        $nobility = "nobilityFour";
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->users SET mg_nobility='$nobility' WHERE user_email='$email'"));
    }        
}
```

Comment: [enable debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and [look at the examples for how to correctly use `prepare`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Comment: Mmmm the query is ok, I used it before